# can I know when trying to select disabled md-checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I know it is strange question but when I have disabled md-checkbox,
is there any way to know when someone trying to select it?

**Edit 1**

in my application I have 2 modes 
 view mode 
 edit mode 
 in edit mode the check box will be disabled so the user can't select it untill he back to view mode but I am afraid that the user will be confused why the check box is diabled 
 so I want when he try to select check box in edit mode to show message that **you are in Edit mode** to tell him why he can't select check box

Comment: Well, the `disabled` attribute prevents any click events. Can you explain **why** you want this?

Comment: bind it to a click event e.g. ngClick if you really have too, but I agree with @devqon